# How to set up XenServer with OpenBSD?

Tags: xenserver

I've worked with VirtualBox before, but am new to XenServer.

I have XenServer 6.5 set up on a computer on my LAN. This computer has one NIC, with IP 192.168.1.1 . Do I need more than one NIC?

I can connect to XenServer with XenCenter from my Windows laptop, as well as via SSH.

Do I set up "External Network"?

Comment: Check if a NIC is there in OpenBSD, from memory only FreeBSD was 100% Xen ready.

Comment: @yagmoth555 it has re0 interface, and vlan0 interface

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself.

1. You don't need more than one NIC on the XenServer host
2. Use OpenBSD 5.9 [I was using 5.8]
3. Allow Intel NIC emulation, as per https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/329848-openbsd-with-message-watchdog-timeout/

Or:

```
[root@XenServer ~]#
[root@XenServer ~]# cd /root/
[root@XenServer ~]# wget http://www.wansec.com/Downloads/XenServer/qemu-dm-wrapper.patch
[root@XenServer ~]# patch -p0 < qemu-dm-wrapper.patch
```

In XenCenter, select the VirtualMachine for which you desire to change the NIC emulation to e1000. Right click, and select Properties. In the Properties window, on the left side, select "Custom Fields". Click the "Edit Custom Fields" button. Click Add. For the name field type "NicEmulation" exactly as shown without the quotes. The Type: field will be "Text".  Click OK. Now you will see a field where you can enter "e1000" for NicEmulation. Click OK. Start, or Restart your Virtual Machine.

Comment: Good info, I'am happy to see obsd can now work good. (I'am not the DV btw)